# Topology question (square hole in cylinder)

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

I have a cylindric shaped mesh with two faces that has been extruded into the cylinder. I am using subsurf and the extruded part is naturally curved due to the subsurf. 
I need the extruded part to be almost 100% cubic and not curved. I know i am probably doing this wrong but right now i dont know any other way.
Creasing doesnt give a decent result so that is out of the question. Model it another way? Interesting but how?
Or maybe there is a solution to my problem?

I have added a screenshot to ilustrate.[image]

Comment: Hello :). What exactly do you mean by "creasing doesn't give a decent result"? It seems to work great on my end.

Comment: The mesh in the ilustration is not the same mesh as i am doing this on. That mesh has diferent topology. I reckoned that a posible solution to my question would remove the issue anyway. Sorry for not being precise in the information given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of topology will work fine for a 16 vertex cylinder, a bit more complicated for a 12 vertex cylinder:

[image]

There's a trick to avoid pinching with the *Shrinkwrap* modifier:

Create a cylinder at the exact same place and with the exact same diameter. Hide it.

[image]

On your original cylinder, create a vertex group around the square hole.

[image]

Give your cylinder a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the hidden cylinder as *Target* and *Vertex Group* > Choose the group you've created.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that looks like a good solution. Only i dont know how you made that. And how can i do that without mirror?

Comment: ok I've edited, you need to begin with a bevel, then join some vertices and dissolve edges

Comment: This is a good solution. It didnt make the are completely square like i wished, but it is so close.....

Comment: Then you need to begin with more vertices, like a 32 vertex cylinder

Comment: I tried that too, it doesnt get completely squared but its close.

Comment: Do you know how i can get rid of the deformation in the corners? It is hardly visible but i am a perferctionist.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can try with the Shrinkwrap modifier

Comment: I will try that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loopcuts on the part of the cylinder extruded inwards, and it will sharpen the side the closer you move the cut to each side. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to add a loop cut to a side in edit mode.

Comment: Using edgeloops like you say only makes the loops follow the shape that the subsurf provides. It does not make the area squared,,,